# Direct Sum, Vectors in vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: $V$ vector space, $ v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 $ are vectors in V which are different from one another.

If $V = Sp\{v1,v2\} \oplus Sp\{v3,v4\}$ then $ v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 $ are not necessary independent.

I showed that by saying that: $V = R^2$ , $\{v_1,v_2\} = \{(1,0),(2,0)\}$ and $\{v_3,v_4\} = \{(0,1),(0,2)\}$

If $V = Sp\{v1,v2\} \oplus Sp\{v3,v4\}$ then

It means that their sum is $V = \{(1,0),(2,0),(0,1),(0,2)\} = R^2 $

And their intesection is $\{(0,0)\}$.

But, $v_2 = 2*v_1$ and $v_4 = 2*v_3$ which means that they are dependent, thus they are not necessary independent.

Did I prove it right or I have any mistakes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems correct

Comment: Thanks WLOG! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If $V = U \oplus W$ and *V* is finite dimensional, then because $U \cap W = \{ 0 \}$ $Dim(V) = Dim(U) + Dim (W)$

So, if you take as an example $R^2$ with dimension $2$ when you represent it as the direct sum of two non-empty subspaces then they will each have dimension $1$, and as you see when you have a spanning set of more than one vector for a $1$ dimensional space then they must be linearly dependant.

In general, if V is finite dimensional and $V = U \oplus W$ then $Dim (V) = Dim (U) + Dim (W) $which is equivalent to saying that if $S_U $ and $  S_W$ are spanning sets for $U, W$ then there must be at least $Dim(V)$ vectors in total in  $S_U $ and $  S_W$ . If there exactly $Dim(V)$ then they must be linearly independent, and if more, then they will be linearly dependent.

Comment: Yes, but my question was to give an example of 4 vectors to prove that it's not necessary linearly independent. And as you said, generally, it true. But I had to show an example.

Comment: It's a good example: I added a little background for you.